# Creating an order in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Hi everyone I have a few questions about the django admin.

First the relevant details. I currently have Client, Printer, Cartridge, and Order models.

The Printer model has a ManyToManyField to the Cartridge model, which would allow you to select all the cartridges that can be used with that printer.

The Cliente has a ManyToManyField to the printers which they own.

1) I want to create an Order through the Django admin which lets your specify the Client, a dicount, and multiple cartridges through a ManyToManyField. This is getting kinda tricky because I have to do it through another table that specifies whether it's a new Cartridge or a refill.

2) I want the admin to filters the Cartridges to only show the ones that belong to the printers that they own.

3) Also I would like to have a field that holds the total price of their order, but it should calculate it based on how many cartridges they have added to the order. I don't know if this should be done by adding more of the same cartridge to the order or by having another field in the related table that specifies the quantity.

Can this be done in the admin or do I need to use a form? And if so how would I go about adding this to the admin? It seems difficult and probably something I will have to do in multiple parts since in order to filter the list of cartridges I have to know the client beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, no, it's not really possible. The development version has some [methods for limiting foreign keys](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), but it doesn't seem to me that limiting based on the customer is possible, since it depends on separate foreign keys.

The best suggestion, if you're really bent on doing it in the admin form, would be to use Javascript to do it. You would still have to make AJAX calls to get lists of what printers customers had and what cartridges to show based on that, but it could be done. You would just specify the JS files to load with [the Media class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions).

But I think that's more work than it's worth. The easiest way I would see to do it would be with [Form Wizards](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/). That way, you'd have a step to select the customer so on the next step you know what cartridges to show.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've worked similar problems, and have come to the conclusion that in many cases like this, it's really better to write your own administration interface using forms than it is to try and shoehorn functionality into the admin which is not intended to be there.

As far as 3) goes, it depends on what your product base looks like. If you're likely to have customers ordering 50 identical widgets, you probably do want a quantity field. If customers are more likely to be ordering 2 widgets, one in red, one in blue, add each item separately to the manytomany field and group them in your order interface.